# App crashes with setValuesForKeysWithDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, key-value-coding

I am using setValuesForKeysWithDictionary to populate my model object . Model object is defined as

```
@interface Media : NSObject
{
    NSString *userId;
    NSString *mediaType;
}

@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *userId;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *mediaType;
```

property synthesization looks like ,

```
@implementation Media
@synthesize userId;
@synthesize mediaType;
```

and I initialize the class as follows,

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[dic setValue:@"aaa" forKey:@"userId"];
[dic setValue:@"bbb" forKey:@"mediaType"];

Media *obj = [[Media alloc] init];
[obj setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dic];
```

This crashes with the message

```
'[<Media 0x8a9f280> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant    for the key aaa.'
```

How come setValuesForKeysWithDictionary: treat my value as the key ?? or have I misunderstood the purpose of the setValuesForKeysWithDictionary: function ?

Comment: Where are you putting this code?  I copied the code below "and I initialize the class as follows" into my app delegate, and defined a new class Media with the .h file you show.  It worked fine for me.

Comment: My initial thought is that it has something to do with how/if you are synthesizing your properties in the implementation of Media. I can't reproduce your issue with the latest version of Xcode (4.4.1) though because synthesizing is done automatically.

Comment: Actually for testing purposes I am trying out this in appDelegate, I am splitting hairs all night because of this issue. So weird.

Comment: I am using xCode 4.3.3.  and what's funny is If I modified it to  [dic setValue:@"userId" forKey:@"userId"];
[dic setValue:@"mediaType" forKey:@"mediaType"]; , It runs without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer. It wasn't about setting the values rather the retrieval part. I was using the following method to read back the values from the model.

```
-(NSDictionary*) dictionaryRepresentation
{ 
   return [self dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:,userId,mediaType,     nil]];
}
```

As you can see I have used plain variable names instead of keys. @"userId", @"mediaType".

I changed xcode to a different font theme recently and still getting used to the new set of font colors. Thanks guys for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Add @objc as prefix while declaring the variable like this.

```
class Customer: NSObject
{
    @objc var name: String?
    @objc var email: String?
}
```

It should work.

Comment: That looks like swift and has nothing do to with the question.